# How to generate multiple PDF to zip using angular

Tags: angular, pdf, zip

I don't know how to generate multiple pdf file then download in zip using angular

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

you could use [jspdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jspdf) to create your pdf files and use [jszip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jszip) to download created files in zip file.